# Entity Framework Core Coalesce null value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a database that I am unable to change, where the individual in that database has a gender which is (most of the time) 'M' / 'F'. There are some instances where the gender is null.

On the database (Oracle) this is defined as `Gender CHAR(1 BYTE)` column in the database.

The following query, allows me to do what I'd expect in SQL and wrap this column in a coalesce function

```
var result = from x in _context.Individuals where x.Id == 502429 select new { Sex = x.Sex ?? "U" };
```

Produces this SQL... (where I'm using "u" for "unknown")

```
SELECT COALESCE("x"."GENDER", N'U') "Gender" FROM "INDIVIDUAL" "x" WHERE "x"."Id" = 12345 FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

But, the following doesn't allow me to specify a coalesce option...

```
var someone = await _context
    .Individuals
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(x=>x...)
    .Include(x=>x...)
    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Instead this produces this SQL...

```
SELECT "Individual"."SEX", "..other columns.."
FROM "Individual" "x"
WHERE "x"."Id" = :id_0
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

I have tried specifying a type attribute `[Column("sex", TypeName = "nvarchar(1)")]`, setting a default value on the modelbuilder `modelBuilder.Entity<Individual>().Property(x=>x.Sex).HasDefaultValue`, column type on the modelBuilder `HasColumnType`,

How do I generate the SQL that I'd expect in this instance so that the database performs the work and I get back something I can rely on in my code?

My workaround is to have a string rather than a char type, but that opens a whole other bag of worms, I'd like to be able to use Coalesce with the above..